# Download image from URL and draw it on canvas - Android

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I am trying to download an image from server using Retrofit library. The server returns a byte array of the image, which is then converted to Bitmap using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(..)`. But when I call `canvas.drawBitmap(..)`, my applications crashes and following message is displayed in LogCat

`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x188 android`

After searching on stackoverflow, I came across an answer that said set `android:hardwareAccelerated` to `false`. I did and not only my app got laggy and slow, the image was still not drawn on canvas. I know that the `left` and `top` coordinates passed in `canvas.drawBitmap(....)` are correct as I can display an image that is loaded from mipmap.

Any help on this would be appreciated as I am stuck on this issue for some time now and can't find a suitable solution  to this.

**EDIT**

LogCat at the time of crash

```
                         ----Beginning of crash
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x188 in tid 22133
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.i2c.bb4me-2/lib/x86_64
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
I/MultiDex: install
I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

**Method called for fetching and drawing Image**

I am calling this method in `onDraw()` after calculating left and top which are correct like I said above.

```
private void getBitmap(final Canvas canvas, long imageID, final float left, final float top, final Paint paint) {
        ProfileService profileServiceRetrieveImage = AppManager.getServiceManager().getService(ProfileService.class);
        Call<ServerResponse<FetchProfileImageResponse>> call = profileServiceRetrieveImage.fetchProfileImage("retrieveImage.action", "", imageID);
        call.enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<ServerResponse<FetchProfileImageResponse>>() {
            @Override
            protected void onSuccess(ServerResponse<FetchProfileImageResponse> objectServerResponse) {
                FetchProfileImageResponse dao = objectServerResponse.getResponsePayload();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dao.getBinaryData(), 0, dao.getBinaryData().length);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, left, top, paint);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you try with Picasso or Glide? They are very good library for image.

Comment: Yes, I know about those libraries. But I can't use them. The architecture followed at my workplace doesn't allow using them

Comment: Are you shure decodeByteArray does not return null? If your app crashes you will have errors/exceptions mentioned in the LogCat. Please post them.  Something mre then one line.

Comment: I am confident that it does not return null. I have debugged it and validated every field. And there is no exception/errors in the logcat except for that one line.

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of logcat, @greenapps

Comment: Please post text. As we do not want to retype anything.

Comment: @greenapps please check now

Comment: `MultiDex support library is disabled`

Comment: `my applications crashes `. Cannot you prevent that with some try-catch?

Comment: @greenapps thank you so much for your time and support. I got the issue fixed finally. Thanks, again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution in case anyone out there is stuck on this issue like me.

First of all, don't call `canvas.drawBitmap(....)` in the `onSuccess`. Just save the bitmap retrieved from `onSuccess` in a class, call `invalidate()` and call `canvas.drawBitmap(...)` in `onDraw()`